# How to get navigation from google maps and send it to a peripheral?

Tags: android, react-native, google-maps, navigation, iot

Just like android auto I want that my app connect with a peripheral device via ble connection send the navigation symbols to it when navigation is set on google maps app.

Tried searching, but only found solutions to integrate maps to my application, but i want to send data from google maps to peripheral via my app running in background.

Comment: if you are able to integrate Google maps into your app, then isn't your real question `how to send data to the peripheral?` ?

Comment: I don't want to integration google maps directly to my app, i want my app running in background to get navigation info when google maps navigation is used.